# Java convert to km

Tags: java, parsing, integer, double

I am trying to use this code to convert the kilometers you input in the textfield to miles... but it wont work. 
Can anyone help me with this ?

```
private void btn_convertActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    String str2 = "0.621";

    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(txt_input.getText());
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(str2);
    lbl_converted.setText("" + (num1 * num2));
    ...
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Doesn't work"?

Comment: You might want to use float or double instead of int. int can only hold full numbers.

Comment: Define doesnt work; exception, wrong answer, does nothing at all?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider That's a valid answer, post it as an answer.

Comment: I usually don't post answers I haven't tested (and I am unable to do so right now)

Comment: Also (not strictly relevant to your problem), life will get harder and harder if you use variable names like "str2", try to use expressive variable names

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Sometimes you don't really need to test it, it's obvious.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Anytime that thought goes through my head it means I'm about to commit changes that break stuff =P.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use floating point numbers. In this case `Integer` is not the type you need. Use `Double` instead(and something like `Double.parseDouble(txt_input.getText());` ). Also you don't need str2 to be string - use a double constant instead.

Comment: Awesome! Have it working now. Im trying to learn java :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Integer` use `Double` for parsing

Answer (score 0):

`"0.621"` is not an integer number - try using a double or float instead.

Also, there is no need to put it in a String in the first place, just use a double literal like

```
final double num2 = 0.621;
```

Note that Integer.parseInt may throw a NumberFormatException, which should be handled.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
final double converter = 0.621;
double num = Double.parseDouble("45");
double answer = num * converter;
```

This way you don't even have to parse the already known value. You can even make it a constant as the converter will not change

Answer (score 0):

Just Change your code as below :

```
private void btn_convertActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

   double num1 = Double.parseDouble(txt_input.getText());

    lbl_converted.setText("" + (num1 * 0.621));
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using String as numbers, and that isn't the correct way of handling the problem because when parsed to an int you get a wrong number that may be only the integer part of the double. In your case you will have that the constant of conversion is zero. your code should be:

```
private void btn_convertActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    double conversionConstant = 0.621;

    int input = Integer.parseInt(txt_input.getText());
    double kmToMiles = conversionConstant * input;
    lbl_converted.setText("" + kmToMiles);
    ...
}
```

This is reasonably ok, but it will fail if the use input a non integer value, like is `1.5` or a NaN (Not a Number)

this should be the complete solution to your problem:

```
private void btn_convertActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    final double CONVERSION_CONSTANT = 0.621;

    String inputText = txt_input.getText();

    double input;
    try{
        input = Double.parseDouble(txt_input.getText());
        double kmToMiles = conversionConstant * input;
        lbl_converted.setText("" + kmToMiles);
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.println("You have typed a wrong input. Only numbers are allowed");
    }

}
```